# Greedy Selection of Non-overlapping Intervals

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bioinformatics, greedy

I'm trying to implement an algorithm described in [this paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/10/2329.full) (The GBDP strategy, "matching distance") and need a bit of clarification.

Basically, the problem is that I have a list of items where each item has a length and an interval (It's actually two intervals, but it's the same idea).

```
ID    LENGTH    START    END
1     1000      1        1000
2     20000     5        20005
3     20        30500    30520
4     500       30500    31000
5     200       900      1100
```

The goal is to find a subset of items with non-overlapping ranges. In the paper, they say they first sort the items by length

```
ID    LENGTH    START    END
2     20000     5        20005
1     1000      1        1000
4     500       30500    31000
5     200       900      1100
3     20        30500    30520
```

and then proceed to "greedily choosing a subset of [items] with non-overlapping intervals." Here's where I'm confused. I know what a greedy algorithm is, but I'm not sure what the authors mean here. I guessed it could be that they simply go through the list, keeping only those items that don't overlap with the ones above them.

```
ID    LENGTH    START    END
2     20000     5        20005
4     500       30500    31000
5     200       900      1100
3     20        30500    30520
```

Notice that, with this approach, the result still includes items with overlapping ranges (4 and 3).

I managed to easily implement this approach in Perl, but I'm thinking it's probably not what the authors intended. Do they mean keeping items that don't overlap with *any* of the other items above them? I'd appreciate if someone explained what "greedy selection" means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct almost to the end (and in the point where not, you raise the correct interpretation as an option).

First, as you say, sort things so that lengths are decreasing:

```
ID    LENGTH    START    END
2     20000     5        20005
4     500       30500    31000
5     200       900      1100
3     20        30500    30520
```

Now we will greedily choose intervals as long as they don't conflict with *any* of the previous ones chose. So, with the chosen set initially empty,

1. Initially, 2 is the greediest choice we can make (the length is 20000). It doesn't conflict, and so we add it to the chosen set.
2. Ditto for 4, and 5. The chosen set is now *{2, 4, 5}*.
3. The next greedy (as well as simply remaining) choice is 3. Since it does conflict with *any* of the previous ones, namely 4, we cannot use it.

The result is *{2, 4, 5}*, therefore.

---

FYI, this is closely related to a well-known problem in computer science - Interval Scheduling. If you're trying to optimize the total *number* of matches, and not the total *length* of matches, you [sort by end position and greedily choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#Greedy_polynomial_solution).

Comment: Thank you. I think I can use Perl's IntervalTree to do that.

The ultimate purpose is actually to find the genetic distance between two or more sequences (DNA, for example) based on the intervals of sequence alignment. Longer alignments are considered more significant, so we want to be biased to keeping them.